# Taylor Series error range

Tags: calculus

I haven't been able to get an answer yet on math stack so I figured some physics people could help me out (although my question will probably get moved back to math soon hopefully not)

Question

> $$\int_0^x\cos(t^2)dt \ = \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)(2n)!}$$
>   Use the fifth degree Taylor polynomial to approximate $\int_0^1\cos(t^2)dt $. Then, find an upper bound on the error in your approximation.

I do not understand why a range of values for the error even exists. The approximation I get is $\frac{9}{10}$. The actual value of $\int_0^1\cos(t^2)dt $ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)(2n)!}$. This series converges to some value. This value would then be the exact value of $\int_0^1\cos(t^2)dt $. So, we know there exists a value for which the series is convergent, and this is what we want to approximate. We already know our approximation ($\frac{9}{10}$). Find the difference between the approximation and the value where the series converges and we get our error. There is no range for this error. It just exists as a single value. So, how can there be a range of values for this error?

Comment: Is there an upper bound you can find without actually calculating an infinite number of terms and summing them up?

Comment: The actual error is a concrete value, as you say, but it is a value that one can't compute unless you have the exact value. What they want you to provide is a known (and as good as you can) bound for that error. For example, if you have an alternating series, the partial sums of the series converge to the sum from the left and the right, alternating the side. Therefore, if you take the difference $D$ between two consecutive partial sums, you know that the distance between the first partial sum and the sum of the series is less than $D$. The value of $D$ is just the value of the next term.

Comment: Another example. If the series that you are summing is a Taylor series, then you have [the Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder). It is expressed in terms of the value of a derivative of the function at an *unknown* point. However, if it happens that you know a global bound of that derivative, then you can bound the remainder (error) of the series.